# TypeError while using an function with an input as an argument

Tags: python, function, input, arguments, typeerror

When I tested this code and typed a number,

```
cost = int(input("Enter cost of meal: "))

def get_cost():
    return cost

def compute_tip(cost):
    tip = (cost*0.18)+cost
    return tip

def compute_tax(cost):
    tax = (cost*0.825)+0.825
    return tax

def main():
    print("Cost:    $" + str(get_cost()))
    print("Tip: $" + str(compute_tip()))
    print("Tax: $" + str(compute_tax()))
    print("Total:   $" + str(get_cost() + compute_tip() + compute_tax()))

main()
```

it showed that I have an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HW05B.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "HW05B.py", line 16, in main
    print("Tip: $" + str(compute_tip()))
TypeError: compute_tip() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Could anyone give me ideas on how to pass the error? Thanks!

Comment: The error message is very clear. `compute_tip` requires you to provide `cost` as an argument, but you didn't do that.

Comment: The error specifies that it requires one argument (i.e.in this case the **cost**)

Answer (score 0):

Assign a variable in the main method to capture the value you get from get_cost :

```
int(input("Enter cost of meal: "))

def get_cost():
    return cost

def compute_tip(cost):
    tip = (cost*0.18)+cost
    return tip

def compute_tax(cost):
    tax = (cost*0.825)+0.825
    return tax

def main():
    cost = get_cost()
    tip = compute_tip(cost)
    tax = compute_tax(cost)
    print("Cost:    $" + str(cost))
    print("Tip: $" + str(tip))
    print("Tax: $" + str(tax))
    print("Total:   $" + str(cost + tip + tax))

main()
```

[image]

Comment: better to capture the values of `compute_tip` and `compute_tax` as well, rather than calling them again in the total.

Comment: Oh, I guess I forgot that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the way you have defined the functions. In `compute_tip(cost)`and in 
`compute_tax(cost)` you have passed an argument "cost". So you program expects you to pass an argument whenever you define these functions. 
Your function `get_cost()` does not use an argument and hence works fine.

So any of these will work well:

```
cost = int(input("Enter cost of meal: "))

def get_cost():
    return cost

def compute_tip(cost):
    tip = (cost*0.18)+cost
    return tip

def compute_tax(cost):
    tax = (cost*0.825)+0.825
    return tax

def main():
    print("Cost:    $" + str(get_cost()))
    print("Tip: $" + str(compute_tip(cost)))
    print("Tax: $" + str(compute_tax(cost)))
    print("Total:   $" + str(get_cost() + compute_tip(cost) + compute_tax(cost)))

main()
```

Or,

```
cost = int(input("Enter cost of meal: "))

def get_cost():
    return cost

def compute_tip():
    tip = (cost*0.18)+cost
    return tip

def compute_tax():
    tax = (cost*0.825)+0.825
    return tax

def main():
    print("Cost:    $" + str(get_cost()))
    print("Tip: $" + str(compute_tip()))
    print("Tax: $" + str(compute_tax()))
    print("Total:   $" + str(get_cost() + compute_tip() + compute_tax()))

main()
```

Thanks for asking. 
Have a great day.